# How do I translate a message from my message.properties file interpolating a parameter?

Tags: angularjs

This is my message.properties:

```
# Dialogos
dialogo.titulo.confirmarExclusaoSistema=CONFIRMA?
dialogo.mensagem.confirmaExclusaoSistema=Confirma a exclus\u00E3o do sistema {0} ?
```

Function calling the dialog inside my controller:
`sistema.nome` contains the value I need to interpolate.

```
    function excluirSistema(index){
        var sistema = controller.sistemas[index];
        var dlg = dialogs.confirm($translate.instant('dialogo.titulo.confirmarExclusaoSistema'), 
                $translate.instant('dialogo.mensagem.confirmaExclusaoSistema'));
        dlg.result.then(function(data){         
            sistemaService.excluirSistema(sistema.id).then(function(data){
                controller.sistemas.splice(index, 1);
                notifier.success(data.messages);                                
            });
        });
    }
```

The message I get: `Confirma a exclusão do sistema {0} ?`
The message I need: `Confirma a exclusão do sistema SOME SYSTEM ?`

How do I get angular to replace the `{0}` with `sistema.nome`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your second message:

```
# Dialogos
dialogo.titulo.confirmarExclusaoSistema=CONFIRMA?
dialogo.mensagem.confirmaExclusaoSistema=Confirma a exclus\u00E3o do sistema {{system}} ?
```

And pass an extra parameter into the second `$translate.instant`:

```
 $translate.instant('dialogo.mensagem.confirmaExclusaoSistema', {system: sistema.nome})
```

Comment: Yes, that worked fine. I actually tried using the interpolation parameters but seems I didn't get the syntax right. Thanks for the answer .